# What file manager/uploader do you use with your embeded wysiwyg editor?

Tags: php, wysiwyg, file-manager

I am looking for a wysiwyg editor to allow user to edit part of their website. I already worked with [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), and heard about [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which both look great. However, they both lack a free (PHP) file manager/uploader, as they sell their own tool to make some money.

I found a few free alternatives for TinyMCE, the best one (for my needs) being [PHP Letter's one](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/), but I was wondering about what the community uses ?

Do you buy the "official" file manager ? Do you code your own ? Or do you have a great (free) alternative ?

Comment: I've been using the old version of CKEditor, `FCKEdit` which is free, and *also* has a file upload manager. Word of warning, the Iframes can be a pain though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this free editor for CKEditor 3.x : [FileManager](http://labs.corefive.com/Projects/FileManager/). I has not been updated for some times though, and seems to have a few bugs. I found a [fork on github](http://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager) that seems to fix some of them and adds quite a few localizations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MooTools File Manager](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_filemanager) and [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152239/ckeditor-customization) on how one might integrate it with CKEditor. Note that the demo for the File Manager is down, so you'll have to download it locally to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the customer is willing to pay the bill, I advise them to buy TinyMCE's File-/ImageManager. Since it integrates nicely, it's transparent to the users.